# Not Able to Push UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with the UI refreshing when I go to push a view controller.  Here's what I'm doing...

So, when a push notification is received by my app, the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is called from my `AppDelegate` and the following is then executed:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

                ReceiptViewController *rv;

                if(screenHeight == 480)
                {
                    rv = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"receiptView2"];
                }else{
                    rv = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"receiptView"];
                }
                //ReceiptViewController *rv = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"receiptView"];

                rv.orderID = userInfo[@"orderID"];
                rv.driverID = userInfo[@"driverID"];
                rv.cost = [userInfo[@"cost"] intValue];

                [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:rv animated:YES];
```

So here ^, I'm basically redirecting it to a `ViewController` depending on the screen size (3.5 inch or 4 inch).  This works fine.

In my `ReceiptViewController` however, I've got a button with the following action:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PickupViewController *pv;

    if(screenHeight == 480)
    {
        NSLog(@"---------------------------I'm @ 480 Height!!!---------------------------");

        pv = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pickupView2"];
    }else{

        NSLog(@"---------------------------I'm @ 568 Height!!!---------------------------");

        pv = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pickupView"];
    }



    NSLog(@"-------------------Going to PickupViewController!!!!-------------------");

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pv animated:YES];
```

Now here's the weird part.  When the button is tapped and the above block of code is executed, the `init` method in my `PickupViewController` is run (I know this because I'm seeing my `NSLog` come up for it), but I still see the `ReceiptViewController`.  The is responsive though even though it's still on the `ReceiptViewController`.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-----------**EDIT**---------------------

I should also mention that this only happens in the AppDelegate method when push to ReceiptViewController in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method (When I receive a push notification).  If I do the exact same thing in the AppDelegate's applicationWillEnterForeground, with the exact same parameters being passed to the ReceiptViewController, it works just fine.

-----------**UPDATE**---------------------

So I ran the following when the button is tapped:

```
NSUInteger countViews = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count];
    NSString *CurrentSelectedViewController = NSStringFromClass([[self.navigationController visibleViewController] class]);

    NSLog(@"---------------------------Current ViewController => %@, Total ViewControllers on NavController => %tu", CurrentSelectedViewController, countViews);
```

I'm getting back the correct name of the ViewController & it says the stack count is 7.  Not sure what's going on here... So I'm referencing the right navigation controller & it's not null. If I do something like:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I'm getting back EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000196c181d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x000000018d6fd040 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 20
2   UIKit                           0x000000018d6e651c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 372
3   UIKit                           0x000000018d6fca40 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 580
4   UIKit                           0x000000018d6fc6d4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 688
5   UIKit                           0x000000018d6f736c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1168
6   UIKit                           0x000000018d6c8b4c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 252
7   UIKit                           0x000000018d6c6c3c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 8496
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a6bf7f0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a6beb4c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 252
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a6bcde4 __CFRunLoopRun + 628
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018a5fddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
12  GraphicsServices                0x00000001902e5c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
13  UIKit                           0x000000018d72efc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
14  AriaBlackCar                    0x000000010004baf0 main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001971fba9c start + 0
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, did you check that your pushViewController code is executed on the main thread?

Comment: Please, clear your question, what exactly do u ask.

Comment: Hi, yes it's running on the main thread.

Comment: My question is why is my UI not refreshing to the PickupViewController

Comment: have u set any storyboard id for ur PickupViewController

Comment: Yes, I'm able to push it with the exact same code from another ViewController

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: May `self.navigationController` be null ?

Comment: Just checked, it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use segue as an alternative for this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pv animated:YES];
```

because some time the this line not work. it is an compiler error. and clean the build folder of your app. using command+shift+alter+k.
And test it in device. 
This solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

// creating a object of storyboard           
 UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"name of your view controller"];

// creating a view controller and after that pushing it            
                                                                         [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

The `init` in the `PickupViewController` is being called from this line:

```
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pickupView2"];
```

That's why you get the `NSLog` from the `PickupViewController`. From what I understand, the navigation part is failing. Try calling the navigation controller as you did in the first block, e.g.

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:rv animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIStoryboard *storyboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
     // creating a object of storyboard

```
 

UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"name of your view controller"];
```

// creating a view controller and after that pushing it

```
    [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
```